# ggplot statistical differences in plot labels (reproducible code included)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a code that generates two plots (actually from different datasets) like this one:

```
#Plot 1
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),fill=factor(gear)))+
    geom_bar(position="fill")+
    geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..))),
              stat='count',position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))


#Plot 2
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),fill=factor(gear)))+
    geom_bar(position="fill")+
    geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..))),
              stat='count',position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))

plot <- p1 + p2
plot
```

Is it possible using gglpot o other library to test statistical differences among factos and if there are statistical differences among them to change the label from 25% from something like "25% ↑" or "25% ** " so what I want is to compare values and change labeling to include statistical differences. In my example values are the same but in reality plots are coming from different datasets.

Comment: I would discourage you from trying to use `ggplot` for statistical tests. It's a plotting library so just let it do the plotting. If you need to test a statistical hypothesis, you should do that outside of `ggplot`. But you'll need to decide what statistical test is appropriate for your data to test for a "statistical difference." There are tons of tests you can choose from depending on what types of data you have and assumptions you want to make about what you are trying to estimate.

Answer (score 1):

As MrFlick mentioned, ggplot might not be the right tool to do the calculations. But once you have your calculations, you could do something like that

```
# some date with calculated levels of significance
dplyr::tibble(YEAR=rep(c(2019,2020),eac=3),
              GRP=rep(c("A","B","C"),2),
              VAL=c(20,100,30,25,70,30),
              SIG=rep(c("*","***",""),2)) %>%
  # create labels
  dplyr::group_by(GRP) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(LABEL=dplyr::case_when(VAL/sum(VAL)<0.5 ~ paste("<",SIG),
                                       VAL/sum(VAL)>0.5 ~ paste(">",SIG),
                                       TRUE ~ paste(""))) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  # calculate percentages
  dplyr::group_by(YEAR) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(VAL=VAL/sum(VAL)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  # plot data: combining percentages and sig-levels as label
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=YEAR,
                               y=VAL,
                               fill=GRP,
                               label=glue::glue("{scales::percent(VAL)} {LABEL}"))) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  ggplot2::geom_text(position=ggplot2::position_fill(0.5))
```